# When should an item have its own controller in MVC architecture?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, controller

I'm currently build an MVC application (ASP.NET particularly, but I suppose this is a broader question as well). I've seen this asked on SO in a couple of different contexts, but I wasn't able to get clarity for my own situation from those discussions. I have controllers such as:

- HomeController
- AccountController
- EventController (our customers have events)
- MenuController (site navigation)
- ReportController

I also have some items that are less clearly managed with controllers, and this is where my question comes in. After signup, our customers are required to fill out many different aspects of their "Profile", such as business information, payment cards, bank accounts, manager contacts (name/phone).

Currently we've created a "ProfileController", with post/get functions such as:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Business()

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Business(...)
```

It's also going to have something similar for their bank account information, payment cards, managers, etc.

This feels wrong. Should this all be moved into AccountController? Are these items throw-ins that don't really deserve their own controller, or should each of these components have their own controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Developing an MVC application is much kind of developing a REST application, you can apply the principles of REST on developing an MVC application. First you have to think in terms of resources. As per REST, a resource is an entity that can be accessed through an URL.

If you feel each model that you are talking above is a resource and the user can access it through a separate URL then you can go ahead and create a separate controller for each else the single AccountController is fine.

If you sketch the resources and URLS then you can easily identify how many controllers you have to create in your application.

Comment: A user will log in, click on Profile, and then see a summary screen that will allow them to click on individual items to edit things such as Business, Bank Accounts, and Credit Cards. Someone might log in, click Profile > Bank Accounts, and see a list of accounts. They might then click on an individual bank account to edit it. Let's say we have something similar for credit cards, and something to also manage their single business (or multiple businesses down the road). Would these qualify as "resources" per your comment above, or still a legitimate part of AccountController? Thanks

Comment: All of them qualify as resources! I would create a separate "Area" in my MVC project called "Profile" and create separate controllers for each.

Comment: I also will have people registering for events, which is a fairly simple process asking for only a couple of pieces of data. Registrations for an event will need to be initiated by the user (simple enough to be handled in a popup dialog), listed (in a grid), approved (also simple). It's a very simple entity. Would this belong in the EventController, or should I create an EventRegistrationController? It seems with the latter strategy, I could end up with a large number of controllers.

Comment: I think you can put that in EventController itself, after all experience is the best teacher!

Comment: Thanks. Would you still suggest the separate controllers for bank accounts, business(es), and credit cards, as per our earlier discussion (vs. putting them in the AccountController)?